# Infinite list of words

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an infinite list of words.

Something like this:

```
i = 0
option = []
var = ""

while var != "\quit":
    var = input("Insert one word or type '\quit' to exit")
    if var != "\quit":
        option[i] = var
    i = i + 1

print(option)
```

This kind of works when I declare the list like this:

```
option[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: You can `append` to a list: `option.append(var)` instead of `option[i] = var`.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: `"\quit"` is not what you think. The backslash character in strings is an escape sequence character — see [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in the documentation — so you need to write `"\\quit"` (or `r"\quit"`) to put a single backslash at the beginning of a literal string.

Answer (score 1):

Just append to the list. No index variable `i` needed.

```
option = []
while True:
    var = input(r"Insert one word or type '\quit' to exit")
    if var == r"\quit":
        break
    option.append(var)

print(option)
```

Note that I have used `while True` and `break` instead. Your variant will also work.

I have also used raw-strings: strings starting with the prefix `r`, to prevent `\q` being interpreted as a special escape character.

Answer (score 0):

With `options[i] = var` you are assigning a value to the i element of the option list but for adding a new value to the list you should be using the append function `option.append(var)`:

```py
option = []
var = ""
    
while var != "\quit":
    var = input("Insert one word or type '\quit' to exit")
    if var != "\quit":
        option.append(var)
print(option)
```